# Creating Directory Structure with Vagrant + Chef

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

For my CentOS Virtual Machine(VM), I'd like to create a particular directory structure:

```
/sample/one
/sample/two
```

Is creating a directory stucture worthy of a Chef cookbook?

Or should I simply use a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef provides a [directory resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_directory.html) for creating directory structures. It includes options for owner, group and permissions. This has worked well for me on past recipes, so give it a shot and see if it fulfills your needs (I can't imagine how it wouldn't).

I may have misunderstood your question, so let me expound.

If you have other resources that you are using Chef to configure (e.g. you want a database to put its data in a separate folder location), I would put the directory definition in with the cookbook recipe you are using to configure that resource.

If the directories are only being used by something other than Chef resources (e.g. you want a directory for an SSH start location or a shared FTP location), I would create a cookbook specifically named after what the directories are being used for.

If you're JUST creating some directories on a server and don't need to add any other Chef-configured resources to those servers, then you may still benefit from having a Chef cookbook for the task. If you ever need to include those directories on another server which is managed by Chef, or you anticipate the need for other resources to grow over time, a Chef setup could be useful. If this server is a part of an environment and other Chef nodes may need to reference it, it would be very beneficial to have it managed by Chef.

But if you're just making directories on an arbitrary, stand-alone server, then Chef'fing it is probably overkill.

Comment: so I create a whole new cookbook with only the `.rb` file that executes the directory resource commands that you kindly mentioned?